# Is it "<verb> on Mondays to Fridays" or "<verb> from Mondays to Fridays"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I want to state that I cook on Mondays, Tue, Wed, Thur, and Fri, in my house every week. Should I say "I cook on Mondays to Fridays" or "I cook from Mondays to Fridays", or something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any of the following are OK, and synonymous:

1. *I cook Monday to Friday.*
2. *I cook Monday through Friday.*
3. *I cook Mondays through Fridays.*
4. *I cook from Monday to Friday.*
5. *I cook on Monday through Friday.*

As you can see, the first preposition is unnecessary, as is the plural.

If you insist on having two prepositions for some reason, *from ... to* and *on ... through* seem more likely to me, but that may be just my personal preference.

This is one of those constructions where there's a lot of possible choices that don't make any difference, as long as you avoid distractions. After all, it's such an expected situation that it gets abbreviated as just ***M-F*** most of the time.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can spare yourself the trouble and just say:

*I cook every day except **on** weekends/the weekend.* (AE)

*I cook every day except **at** weekends/the weekend.* (BE)

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'every day'?

Comment: Can I say "I cook every day except weekends"?

Comment: I would say "I cook every weekday".

Comment: @JAM You're right, corrected!

Comment: @Tigerhead I believe you can't and I think you must use one of the two prepositions for it to make sense. If you are enumerating weekdays and want to exclude a specific day or days (in this case, the weekend), you'd say: "... except weekends", but, you're actually not, you're excluding weekends because you're not doing your daily activity "on" those specific days.
In my opinion, it's more accurate to say "on" or "at" weekends.

Answer (score 2):

There is a minor semantic difference:

'Cooking *on* Mondays to Fridays' allows that you may cook on Mondays to Fridays *between 9am and 4pm*

'Cooking *from* Mondays to Fridays' allows that you may cook **from** Monday to Friday (24hr continuously), for the Monday-to-Friday cycle *of each and every week*.

The latter is unlikely in context to the verb, but may be more than appropriate for other verbs, such as industrial manufacturing processes.